# How do I determine if two math vectors are the same?

Tags: java, math, vector, methods

I need to determines if two vectors are almost equal (similar). Two vectors are similar if the magnitude of their vector difference is smaller than the specified tolerance (tol) other - the other vector to compare tol the threshold length of the vector difference (this - other) returns true if the length of (this - other) is less than tol, and false otherwise.

Here is my method:

```
public boolean similarTo(Vector2 other, double tol) {
   boolean result = false;
   double z = this.mag() - other.mag();
   if (z < tol) {
       result = true;
   }
   else {
       result = false;
   }
   return result;
}
```

However, this does not seem to work, as when I run the JUnit test I get a java.lang.AssertionError, nothing else. Any help would be appreciated. By the way, the mag() method is already written and working properly.

EDIT: Here is the JUnit test:

```
@Test
public void test15_similarTo() {
    double rad = 0.34;
    double x = Math.cos(rad);
    double y = Math.sin(rad);
    Vector2 unit = new Vector2(x, y);
    for (int i = -6; i <= 6; i++) {
        double tol = Math.pow(10.0, i);

        // if we scale unit by maxScale we will be at the limits of similarity
        double maxScale = 1.0 + tol;
        double scale = Math.nextAfter(maxScale, Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY);
        Vector2 w = new Vector2(scale * x, scale * y);
        assertTrue(unit.similarTo(w, tol));

        scale = Math.nextAfter(maxScale, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY);
        w = new Vector2(scale * x, scale * y);
        assertFalse(unit.similarTo(w, tol));
    }
}
```

Comment: can you also post the JUnit tests?

Comment: just posted the test.

Comment: In addition to checking the lengths, you also need to check that the angles are the same.

Comment: the angles are not needed/ required as I'm told not to use the angles

Comment: Surely you must take the absolute value of the difference, no? If `this.mag()` equals 0.0 and `other.mag()` equals 1e20, your method returns `true`.

Comment: Thanks James I did have to take the absolute value.

Comment: You write 'the magnitude of their vector difference' but your code computes the difference of the magnitudes. These are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution (for anyone interested):

```
public boolean similarTo(Vector2 other, double tol) {
   boolean result = false;
   double z = Math.abs(this.mag() - other.mag());
   if (z < tol) {
       result = true;
   }
   else {
       result = false;
   }
   return result;
}
```